# VB Disabling textboxes after button is pressed.

Tags: vb.net

is there a way to disable a textbox in code only when an even is triggered?
for example, a textbox wants user to enter an initial amount of money in a textbox. After the calculate button is clicked, make the textbox not editable.
im a beginner and my textbook doesnt mention it.

Comment: Yes. All controls have properties like `Enabled` and `Locked` that can be set to true or false.

Comment: And some have `ReadOnly` property.

Comment: Hi @R4g323, welcome to SO. [find](https://www.google.com) some tutorial, it will show you how.

Answer (score 2):

- To disable `textbox` on button click

  ```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      TextBox1.Enabled = False
  End Sub
  ```
- To make it Read Only

  ```
  TextBox1.ReadOnly = True
  ```

  **The difference between `Enabled`  and `ReadOnly` is :**

**Readonly** allows the user to set focus to and select and copy the text but not modify it. 
A **disabled** TextBox does not allow any interaction whatsoever.

Use **ReadOnly** when you have data that you want the user to see and copy, *but not modify*. Use a **disabled textbox**, when the data you are *displaying is not applicable* in for the current state of a dialog or window.